# Clicking element once gives error, clicking it twice works fine, why? (Protractor)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm running end-to-end tests on a website with Protractor, and one of the elements is having a strange behavior. When I first tried specifying the code to click the element once, I got the following error.

Problematic function:

```
  fooField = element(by.css('#inputFoo'));
  foosList = $$('[type=radio]');

  async chooseFoo(id: number) {
    const foo = this.foosList.get(id - 1);
    // await browser.sleep(2000);
    // await this.fooField.click();
    await this.fooField.click();
    await browser.sleep(this.sleepTime);
    await foo.click();
    await this.selectFooButton.click();
  }
```

Error:

```
**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) reimbursement request page should allow a user to register a request
  - Failed: element not interactable
    (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.81)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64)

Executed 2 of 2 specs (1 FAILED) in 28 secs.
[16:50:44] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[16:50:44] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[16:50:44] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[16:50:44] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
```

After changing the code to click on the element twice in a row, and changing nothing else, the code ran successfully. I also tried removing the redundant click and adding a sleep right before the click, but I still got the same error. Why is this happening?

Comment: What does your button do when clicked?

Comment: fooField is an input field that opens a modal with radio buttons when clicked.

Comment: I was calling the element a button in the question title, it's actually an input field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which element you're trying to click, but this way of clicking has helped me when having similar problems:

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', elementToClick);
```

Comment: I'm trying to click this one: fooField = element(by.css('#inputFoo'));

Comment: then try  `browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', fooField);`

Comment: I'm glad! sometimes a scrollIntoView or a mouseMove action will work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
let fooField = element(by.css('#inputFoo'));
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(fooField), 5000, 'Element is not clickable.');
await fooField.click();
```

If the element is not clickable after the certain time will throw error, there is a problem with the button. Something is blocking it, to be clicked.

Another way to bypass it (not the best way) is using javascript click.

```
let fooField = element(by.css('#inputFoo'));
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); arguments[0].click();', fooField);
```

Comment: He mentions that adding a wait before the click did not help so it will be interesting if the EC does solve it

Comment: do you mean the sentence: ' I also tried removing the redundant click' ?

Comment: Yeah that's the one. They mention there was a wait added but never mention how long that wait was

Comment: 2 seconds, it's one of the commented lines on the code

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and got "- Failed: element not interactable". The second suggestion worked (but the scrollIntoView created problems for clicking another element on the same page).